# Using ASP.NET Cache/ViewState/Session

Tags: asp.net, session, caching, viewstate

I'm trying to learn about Cache, Page ViewState, and Session. I created an ASP.NET web app in VS2010 and added 3 text boxes and a button to the page. I run in debug mode, enter random text into each, press the button, and nothing seems to be saved (all text is "null", as you'll see in the code). Am I performing these action in the wrong place? Do I need to add something to the web.config? Here is the code I'm using:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Cache["textbox1"] != null)
                TextBox1.Text = (string)Cache["textbox1"];
            else
                TextBox1.Text = "null";

            if (ViewState["textbox2"] != null)
                TextBox2.Text = (string)ViewState["textbox2"];
            else
                TextBox2.Text = "null";

            if (Session["textbox3"] != null)
                TextBox3.Text = (string)Session["textbox3"];
            else
                TextBox3.Text = "null";
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cache["textbox1"] = "(Cache) " + TextBox1.Text;
        ViewState["textbox2"] = "(VS) " + TextBox2.Text;
        Session["textbox3"] = "(Session) " + TextBox3.Text;
    }
```

And the page header:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="State._Default" EnableSessionState="True" EnableViewState="True" %>
```

Thanks, and sorry for the rookie question. I'm very new to this.

Comment: Would you mind posting the rest of your Default.aspx code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Page_Load` happens before `Button1_Click`. So on `Page_Load` you always replace textbox text with something from statebags (`"null"` at first and then `"(Cache)" + "null"` etc). What you enter in textboxes never lives until `Button1_Click`.

Use Page_PreRender instead.

Comment: It seems that my knowledge of the page lifecycle is severely lacking. Moving the code to OnPreRender accomplished what I was trying to do. Thanks Loki and Muhammad!

Answer (score 1):

Right now, every time you click the button, the code in your Page_Load procedure is overwriting the TextBox.Text values before the Button1_Click event gets a chance to save them.

If you change `if (IsPostBack)` to `if (!IsPostBack)`, the values will only attempt to be loaded from session/viewstate/cache when you initially request the page.  So you would have to request the page, set new values with the button, then re-request (Enter key in address bar) to run the code in Page_Load.

What I would suggest is you create a new button called "Load Values" whose Click event will run the code currently found in your Page_Load.  That way you don't have to tie that code to whether the request was a postback or not.  I think it would make your test results much easier to understand.